# Hibernate cache the persistent Object before update.

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate, my question is simple. The persistent course Object was cached by Hibernate.

I want the user to edit a **Course** and update it in the database.
It can modify the record in the database, however, when I finished the update and redirect to the action which shows the **course** information. The page will cache the **course information** before update.

Say I edited the duration from 3 to 30 . And redirect to the information page, the duration will be 3  , when I refresh , and duration will be 3 again. But when I refresh once again, the duration will be 30. **3->3->30->3->3->30** and so on.
But the database record is actually 30.

I have thought a solution to that, clear the session cache by `session.clear` every time I want to retrieve the database record. But I wonder if it is a good solution.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package short_course_db;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

/**
 *
 * @author jason
 */
public class CourseDAO {

    Session session = null;

    public CourseDAO() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

    public List<Course> getCoursesByKeyWord(String keyword) {
        List<Course> courses = null;
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            keyword = "'%" + keyword + "%'";
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Course as course where course.description like " + keyword);
            courses = q.list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return courses;
    }

    public Course findCourse(int id) {
        Course course = null;
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Course as course where course.id=" + id);
            course = (Course) q.uniqueResult();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return course;
    }

    public List<Course> all() {
        List<Course> courses = null;
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Course order by id");
            courses = q.list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return courses;
    }

    public void updateCourse(Course course) {
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(course);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void saveCourse(Course course) {

        try {

            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(course);
            session.getTransaction().commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with session.flush(); method? Maybe it will help.

Comment: do you mean `session.flush()` after `session.update(course)`? I tried and it didn't help

Comment: I think that then your proposed solution is efficient as far as I can think off. because even by using session.flush() it will send the Object to DB for persistence and if you don't want them to be cached, a subsequent call to session.clear() is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

There are **several** things you should check to make sure the problem is raised by Hibernate.

1. Are you sure your browser's cache is disabled? If not, have you cleared its cache before refreshing?
2. If you are sure of step 1, you may want to disable hibernate cache:

   ```
   session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
   ```
3. If step 2 was not the case, maybe a `flush` is needed to commit changes to DB. *This case happens when your steps take place within a Transaction*

   ```
   session.flush()
   ```